# Limit of the square root of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence such that  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: a_n \geq 0$,
and $a_n$ converges to $a \geq 0$.

Prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{a_n} = \sqrt{a}$$
I tried using the definition of limit and the sandwich theorem but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to show more details : also, search for a duplicate on this site, I am sure you will find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It suffices to see that $$\left|\sqrt {a_n} -\sqrt a\right|=\frac {\left|a_n-a\right|} {\sqrt {a_n} +\sqrt a}\leq \frac {\left|a_n-a\right|} {\sqrt a}<\varepsilon$$ if $|a_n-a|< \varepsilon \sqrt a$.

There could also be a case in which $a = 0$ and then we cannot assume $|a_n-a|< \varepsilon \sqrt a$.

When $a = 0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n > N$ $|a_n| < \varepsilon ^2$
and then $$|\sqrt{a_n}| = \sqrt{a_n} < \varepsilon \iff a_n < \varepsilon ^2 $$
and we showed the rhs is true $\forall n > N$

Comment: Its all great, except you need to prove for the case $a = 0$ because then $\varepsilon \sqrt{a} = 0$ and you cannot assume $|a_n - a| < \varepsilon \sqrt{a}$

Comment: @DanielSegal Thank you very much for pointing out the error an editing the answer. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Since $a_n\to a$ exists $n_0$ such that for any $n\ge n_0$ we have $\left|a_n-a\right|<\epsilon\sqrt a$ and therefore

$$|\sqrt {a_n} - \sqrt a|=\left|\frac{a_n-a}{\sqrt {a_n} + \sqrt a}\right|=\frac{\left|a_n-a\right|}{\sqrt {a_n} + \sqrt a}\le\frac{\left|a_n-a\right|}{ \sqrt a}<\epsilon$$

Comment: Well, it's exactly like Kabo Murphy's answer.

Comment: @ajotatxe Yes I noticed after posting that, even if I've some more detail to justify the assumption.

Comment: That's expected - it's about the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** There’s a more general statement. If $f$ is continuous, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(a_n\right)=f(L).$$ You can prove this by combining the definition of the limit with the definition of continuity.

Comment: Proving continuity of $\sqrt\cdot$ is equivalent to answer the question.

Comment: @ajotatxe Yeah. That’s what I’m pointing out.